# how to display audio output signal on xoscope?

Tags: pulseaudio

Is it possible to display audio output with xoscope?

What I have to pass to `-A` option?

```
xoscope -A ???
```

Comment: `xoscope 1` give `xoscope: can't read 1`

Comment: `-A <device>      select named ALSA-device on soundcard        (default)` (from `xoscope -h`)

Comment: ok maybe then `xoscope -A default` works?

Comment: no, i get `no source`

Comment: If you are using PulseAudio or Pipewire this worked for me on Ubuntu 21.04: 
padsp xoscope